# Microcontroller IDE like simulink

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I have a query that, is there any simulation software available (like simulink in matlab) for micro controllers.
I have tested my system on simulink and generated a c code for it.Now I want to verify the code by running it on a micro controller simulator which also have such scopes etc(so i can easily verify my embedded code).

Comment: Offtopic, but look at Proteus.

Comment: Answer: no. They are too complex/diverse. Look at electronics simulators, they are expensive and complex. But this question is offtopic for SO.

Comment: Simulation is good to a point, but in a microcontroller environment the value of simulation goes down as soon as you need to interact with hardware.  You can certainly simulate that interaction, but there are typically hardware eccentricities that the simulation does not present.

I wonder why you want to simulate the code if the model seems to be working?  I thought the code generation has gotten to a point where it's pretty darn good.  If it were me, I would move to the target.

If you have budget for Matlab/Simulink, you should be able to have a prototype board and emulator/debugger.

Comment: **What particular micro-controller do you have in mind?** - what is the size of your embedded software? What is your time budget? What is your desktop operating system? What C compiler do your use? **Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61681080/edit) your question to give more details.**

Comment: In general no, there is not really a market for such a thing.  you can instrument up qemu on your own to "see" things.  But of course it is very specific to the hardware you want and what you want to see.  if it is just variables kind of like what you see in matlab then that might be done through debuggers, but that would imply the matlab generated code is bad or the compiler is bad.  if it is timing, etc you need hardware you wont have access to anything cycle accurate unless you are aiming at an fpga with a soft core.

Comment: @old_ timer: engineers working at Intel or AMD have access to cycle-accurate simulators: computer chips are today designed with the help of computers.

Comment: right and I have access to simulations of the chips my company uses, but if this person does not already work for the company with the target mcu they wont get access. or even if they did they may not get access as in many of these companies they wont spend that kind of money so any one can likewise want to protect their IP.   Now it is true you can get a copy of the cortex-ms and some other cores from arm if you sign the  NDA and run these on an fpga, I dont know what if any sim capabilities you have but you could build something in the fpga around it....maybe...

Comment: basically if they didnt already have that level of access they wouldnt be asking here, they are asking for a matlab like experience outside matlab for hardware which there really isnt a market for.  matlab is its own deal you are designing control systems and other such things, porting that outside the matlab world is another story...

Comment: @old_timer: it all depends *who you are*.... The [US DoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_DOE) or even my employer [CEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Alternative_Energies_and_Atomic_Energy_Commission) have access to emulators, and I have colleagues developing them.

Comment: because amd/intel rely so heavily on the motherboard and dram timing, etc while in their sim model they get cycle accurate timing, it does not match real world as real world speeds are difficult at best for a number of reasons, first off the sim takes forever because dram is so slow relative to cpu clocks using the cpu clock as the reference clock for the sim, but then you have all of your other system issues plus operating system, etc it can take a week or more sim time just to boot linux on an arm, so windows on a simulated pc would be closer to a month

Comment: again if this person had access they wouldnt be asking this question at stackoverflow.  I have have access to these types of tools and experience using them, been doing it for a long time now.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is a student late on his/her homework, and remotely working from home.

Comment: Instruction set simulators are pretty common - but you need one specific to your particular target and toolchain; they are seldom used because a real micro-controller with on-chip debug is general a more effective solution.  Without specifying what your target is however the question is too broad.  You have to bear in mind also the limitations; a cycle-accurate instruction set simulator is all very well, but a microcontroller for any particular core architecture is likely to have many varied parts with a number of peripherals, then your board will have external components.

Comment: Specify your target and toolchain of choice to get a sensible answer.  Examples: https://www2.keil.com/mdk5/simulation,  http://www.circuitstoday.com/8051-simulator,  https://www.oshonsoft.com/pic.html,  https://sourceforge.net/projects/picsim/ - Google is your friend here.

Answer (score 1):

Xcos is a simulink analogous in Scilab very helpful for most who can't afford a matlab license. The Arduino library will help you making whatever project you want.

You can download it free here https://www.scilab.org/

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to verify the code by running it on a micro controller simulator which also have such scopes et (so i can easily verify my embedded code)

You might consider a [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) approach. Tools like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Coverity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity) or [Clang analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) come to mind. But they are difficult to learn or use. If your code is compilable by some recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)-based [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), consider also developing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

For *some* microcontrollers, you might find software emulators for them (e.g. [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/) lists several of them). [Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) could be a possibility (but again, there is a learning curve).

See also [this](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report....

Take into account your time (including learning efforts). You might decide that buying an [arduino](https://arduino.cc/) (or a [RaspBerryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)) is cheaper than learning to use emulators for it. For example GCC is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), but you'll need months of efforts to dive into its source code (many millions lines of code). [Scilab](https://www.scilab.org//) is also free software. So is [GHDL](http://ghdl.free.fr/).

If you have access to the *entire* documentation of your micro-controller (including cycle times of *every* machine instruction), writing the emulator is also a possibility. Again, budget months of efforts. JIT compilation libraries such as [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) could be interesting to use for that. Or higher-level languages (e.g. [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/)).

Be also aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem), C compilers like [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/), and processor architectures like [RISC-V](https://riscv.org/) or simulator frameworks like [UniSIM](http://unisim-vp.org/)

Notice that automatically assisted verification of C code reduce program bugs, but not software design bugs. You basically move bugs from programs to their specifications (as described by the [V-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model_(software_development)) of software development). There is [*No Silver Bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet)